# Android, Trying to draw/record a bike ride on a map using polylines

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, polyline

I'm still getting to grips with android and trying to make an app that will draw on a Google map the path of where I have cycled. I have successfully displayed the map and can draw a simple polyline between two co-ordinates using this code:

```
//Draws a thin red line from London to New York.
Polyline line = googlemap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
.add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
.width(5)
.color(Color.RED));
```

I've tried to create create a piece of code that is located in the 'LocationChanged' method which I assume will be called each time the location changes and will start doing this as soon as the app is opened (method located at bottom of code). It takes the current location co-ordinates and the previous current location co-ordinates and draws a poly line between them.

I have added a toast in to the Location Changed method so I can see when it is being run however, it is never displayed so I guess something is wrong higher up in the code and it isn't being run/called.

(I have tested the app outdoors with GPS signal and it doesn't draw the line)
(The app runs with no errors but doesn't draw the line)

I'm looking for some assistance in getting the app to draw the line, any help will be much appreciated.

This is my java class file contents:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.Projection;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Record_screen_activity extends FragmentActivity implements
        LocationListener, OnClickListener {

    GoogleMap googlemap, draw;

    Location currentLocation;
    Location myLocation2;

    Button sqlUpdate, sqlView, sqlModify, sqlLoad, sqlDelete, startChrono, pauseChrono;
    EditText sqlNotes, sqlRouteName, sqlLocation, sqlRow;
    TextView sqlDate;
    Chronometer sqlChrono;
    long time = 0;
    int drawing = 1;

//add above here ===========================================================

    // above I am declaring the references that I will use in this file they are
    // linked below to the

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.record_screen); // Names the layout file which
                                                // is linked to this activity


        startChrono = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_Start);
        pauseChrono = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_Pause);


        startChrono.setOnClickListener(this);
        pauseChrono.setOnClickListener(this);


        sqlUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQL_Update);
        sqlRouteName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSQL_RouteName);
        sqlLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSQL_Location);
        sqlNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSQL_Notes);
        sqlChrono = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.c_Timer);
        sqlDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_Date);

//add above here ===========================================================

        // the above lines link the buttons and EditText fields from the xml
        // Layout file to the references stated at the top of this file

        sqlView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQL_View);
        sqlView.setOnClickListener(this);
        sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

        sqlRow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSQL_Rowid);
        sqlModify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQL_Modify);
        sqlLoad = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQL_Load);
        sqlDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSQL_Delete);
        // above references link buttons and tv's to the actual buttons and tv's
        // in th xml file
        sqlModify.setOnClickListener(this);
        sqlLoad.setOnClickListener(this);
        sqlDelete.setOnClickListener(this);

        SupportMapFragment mf = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.mvMain);
        googlemap = mf.getMap();
        googlemap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googlemap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN); // map tiles type can
                                                            // be changed here
                                                            // i.e. to satalite
                                                            // view

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                        false));
        if (location != null) {
            googlemap
                    .animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                                    .getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                            .getLongitude())) // Sets the center of the map to
                                                // location user
                    .zoom(17) // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(0) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(0) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            currentLocation = location;


        }





// Add a thin red line from London to New York.
    //  Polyline line = googlemap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
    //     .add(new LatLng(51.5, -0.1), new LatLng(40.7, -74.0))
        //  .width(5)
             //.color(Color.RED));
// Add a thin red line from London to New York.










//setting the date 

int yy;
int mm;;
int dd;

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        yy = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mm = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        dd = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // set current date into textview
        sqlDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                .append(dd).append("").append("/").append(mm + 1).append("/")
                .append(yy));


    }



    public void onClick(View arg0) {

    switch(arg0.getId()){

    case R.id.b_Start:
        sqlChrono.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + time); //mabe get rid of nanos
        sqlChrono.start();

        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("Route Now Recording"); // sets the dialog box with
                                    // success message
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Please Lock your Screen");
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();

        //sets these variables before the loop is run


        break;







    case R.id.b_Pause:

        time = sqlChrono.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        sqlChrono.stop();

        drawing = 1;


        break;
    }






// ===============================================
// ================Update(save) button============
// ===============================================      
        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.bSQL_Update:
            boolean didItWork = true;
            try {
                String routename = sqlRouteName.getText().toString();
                String location = sqlLocation.getText().toString();
                String notes = sqlNotes.getText().toString();
                String chrono = sqlChrono.getText().toString();
                String date = sqlDate.getText().toString();
//add above here ===========================================================

                SQL_management_activity entry = new SQL_management_activity(
                        Record_screen_activity.this);
                entry.open();
                entry.createEntry(routename, location, notes, chrono, date);
//add above here ===========================================================

                entry.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                didItWork = false;
                String error = e.toString();// the error string will be printed
                                            // to the dialog box to display the
                                            // error code to the user
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Error ohh no..."); // sets the diaog box with
                                                // success mesasge
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            } finally {
                if (didItWork) {
                    // didItWork = true;
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Saving  Route"); // sets the diaog box with
                                                // success mesasge
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Status: Success");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();

                    Thread timer = new Thread() { // this is the same timer as
                                                    // on the spalshcren
                        public void run() { // it automaticaly moves to the
                                            // review page after 500 miliseconds
                            try {
                                sleep(1000); // duration the splash screen is
                                            // displayed for
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                //Intent openMain_menu = new Intent(
                                //      "com.hew235.mapapp.REVIEW_SCREEN_ACTIVITY");
                            //  startActivity(openMain_menu);
                            }

                        }
                    };
                    timer.start();

                }
            }

            break;

        // ===============================================
        // ==================View button================== the end of tutorial
        // 18 will help make a main menu button
        // ===============================================
        case R.id.bSQL_View: // opens the view page
            Intent i = new Intent("com.hew235.mapapp.REVIEW_SCREEN_ACTIVITY");
            startActivity(i);
            break;

        // ===============================================
        // ==================Load button==================
        // ===============================================
        case R.id.bSQL_Load:
            boolean didItWork2 = true;

            try {
                String s = sqlRow.getText().toString();// this string will
                                                        // return whatever is in
                                                        // the edit text
                long l = Long.parseLong(s);// converts whatever is in the above
                                            // string into a long type variable
                SQL_management_activity sma = new SQL_management_activity(this);
                sma.open();
                String returnedRoutename = sma.getRoutename(l);// method
                String returnedLocation = sma.getLocation(l);// method
                String returnedNotes = sma.getNotes(l);// method
                String returnedChrono = sma.getChrono(l);// method
                String returnedDate = sma.getDate(l);// method
//add above here ===========================================================

                sma.close();

                sqlRouteName.setText(returnedRoutename);
                sqlLocation.setText(returnedLocation);
                sqlNotes.setText(returnedNotes);
                sqlChrono.setText(returnedChrono);
                sqlDate.setText(returnedDate);
//add above here ===========================================================

            } catch (Exception e) {
                didItWork2 = false;
                String error = e.toString();// the error string will be printed
                                            // to the dialog box to display the
                                            // error code to the user
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Error ohh no..."); // sets the diaog box with
                                                // success mesasge
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            } finally {
                if (didItWork2) {
                    // didItWork = true;
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Loading Data"); // sets the diaog box with
                                                // success mesasge
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Status: Success");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();

                }
            }
            break;



        // ===============================================
        // ==================Modify button================
        // ===============================================
        case R.id.bSQL_Modify:
            boolean didItWork4 = true;
            try {
                String sRow = sqlRow.getText().toString();
                String mRoutename = sqlRouteName.getText().toString();
                String mLocation = sqlLocation.getText().toString();
                String mNotes = sqlNotes.getText().toString();
                String mChrono = sqlChrono.getText().toString();
                String mDate = sqlDate.getText().toString();


//add above here ===========================================================            

                long lRow = Long.parseLong(sRow);

                SQL_management_activity ex = new SQL_management_activity(this);
                ex.open();
                ex.updateEntry(lRow, mRoutename, mLocation, mNotes, mChrono, mDate); // these are the
                                                                // fields that
                                                                // are being
                                                                // updated
//add above here ===========================================================    

                ex.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                didItWork4 = false;
                String error = e.toString();// the error string will be printed
                                            // to the dialog box to display the
                                            // error code to the user
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Error ohh no..."); // sets the diaog box with
                                                // success mesasge
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            } finally {
                if (didItWork4) {
                    // didItWork = true;
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Modifying Record"); // sets the diaog box with
                                                    // success mesasge
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Status: Success");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();

                    Thread timer = new Thread() { // this is the same timer as//
                                                    // on the spalshcren
                        public void run() { // it automaticaly moves to the//
                                            // review page after 500 miliseconds
                            try {
                                sleep(1200); // duration the splash screen is//
                                                // displayed for
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                Intent openMain_menu = new Intent(
                                        "com.hew235.mapapp.REVIEW_SCREEN_ACTIVITY");
                                startActivity(openMain_menu);
                            }

                        }
                    };
                    timer.start();

                }
            }
            break;

        // ===============================================
        // ==================Delete button================
        // ===============================================
        case R.id.bSQL_Delete:
            boolean didItWork3 = true;
            try {
                String sRow1 = sqlRow.getText().toString();
                long lRow1 = Long.parseLong(sRow1);
                SQL_management_activity ex1 = new SQL_management_activity(this);
                ex1.open();
                ex1.deleteEntry(lRow1);
                ex1.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                didItWork3 = false;
                String error = e.toString();// the error string will be printed
                                            // to the dialog box to display the
                                            // error code to the user
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Error ohh no..."); // sets the diaog box with
                                                // success mesasge
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText(error);
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            } finally {
                if (didItWork3) {
                    // didItWork = true;
                    Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                    d.setTitle("Deleting Record"); // sets the diaog box with
                                                    // success mesasge
                    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                    tv.setText("Status: Success");
                    d.setContentView(tv);
                    d.show();

                    Thread timer = new Thread() { // this is the same timer as
                                                    // on the spalshcren
                        public void run() { // it automaticaly moves to the
                                            // review page after 500 miliseconds
                            try {
                                sleep(1200); // duration the splash screen is
                                                // displayed for
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                Intent openMain_menu = new Intent(
                                        "com.hew235.mapapp.REVIEW_SCREEN_ACTIVITY");
                                startActivity(openMain_menu);
                            }

                        }
                    };
                    timer.start();

                }
            }
            break;

        }
    }

    private static MapController getController() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.map1_screen_activity, menu);
        GoogleMap map;

        return true;
    }


















    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Hello toast! r u hungry";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();


        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location1 = locationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,
                        false));
        if (location1 != null) {
            googlemap
                    .animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                            new LatLng(location1.getLatitude(), location1
                                    .getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location1.getLatitude(), location1
                            .getLongitude())) // Sets the center of the map to
                                                // location user
                    .zoom(17) // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(0) // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(0) // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build(); // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            googlemap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            location1 = currentLocation;

        }



         currentLocation = myLocation2;


                        Polyline line = googlemap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                        .add(new LatLng (myLocation2.getLatitude(), myLocation2
                                .getLongitude()), 
                                new LatLng (currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation
                                        .getLongitude()))
                        .width(5)
                                .color(Color.RED)); 

                        currentLocation = myLocation2; //sets the location variables ready for the lines to join the dots

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "status changed";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: please only include the relevant code and not your whole class

Comment: Have a look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) how to receive location updates.

Comment: Thanks, I've taken a look at the LucationUpdates documentation and have found a sample app which has the updating features which I require

Answer (score 1):

I haven't read all your code but this part, where you supposedly print your line, confuses me:

```
     currentLocation = myLocation2;

     Polyline line = googlemap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
         .add(new LatLng (myLocation2.getLatitude(), myLocation2.getLongitude()), new LatLng (currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude())).width(5)
         .color(Color.RED)); 
     currentLocation = myLocation2; //sets the location variables ready for the lines to join the dots
```

Why are you drawing the Polyline from X to X? this would probably result in an empty line, thus no line at all. Try drawing the line from X to Y instead.